# Log in page not working even though POST variables being queried have a match in user database

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, authentication

I apologize for what will probably be a lengthy post.. I'm fairly new with PHP and trying to get a working registration / log in system for users on my website for a final project.

The log in system was working for registered users until I modified the way registration is validated. I need to have some angular on the website for the project requirements so I created a registration page that looks like this :

**register.php**

```
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" method="post" action= "<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" novalidate>

<p>Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="myusername" value="myusername" ng-model="myusername" required>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.myusername.$dirty">
    <span ng-show="myForm.myusername.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
    </span>
</p>

        <p>Password:<br>
    <input type="password" name="mypassword" value="mypassword" ng-model="mypassword" required>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.mypassword.$error.required && myForm.mypassword.$dirty">Password Required</span>
</p>

<p>Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="myemail" value="myemail" ng-model="myemail" required>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.myemail.$dirty && myForm.myemail.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.myemail.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.myemail.$error.myemail">Invalid email address.</span>
    </span>
</p>





<p>
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="myForm.myusername.$invalid ||  myForm.myemail.$invalid || myForm.mypassword.$invalid">
</p>
```

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))  { //form submission

$newusername = sanitize($_POST['myusername']);                          //sanitize username, email, and password
$newpassword = sanitize($_POST['mypassword']);                                  // encrypt password
$newemail = sanitize($_POST['myemail']);





$sqlname = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '".$newusername."'";      

$result1 = $conn->query($sqlname);
 if  ($result1->num_rows > 0)                          //make sure username does not exist
    {
        echo "
            <script>
            alert('Username already taken. Try again.')
            </script>      
            ";  
    }

$sqlemail = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '".$newemail."'";                        //make sure email does not exist
$result2 = $conn->query($sqlemail);
   if  ($result2->num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo "
            <script>
            alert('That email is already in use.')
            </script>      
            ";
    }

if (($result1->num_rows < 1) && ($result2->num_rows < 1))         //if no results for username or email query register user
{


$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO users SET username = '".$newusername."', password = '".$newpassword."',  email = '".$newemail."'";

$conn->query($sqlinsert);



echo  "".$newusername."  has registered. ";




}
};

?>
```

The registration is working just fine. If I register a user named 'testuser' with 'testpassword' it shows up in the user database.

The issue is now any accounts created with the angular registration are not able to log in. (Accounts created before adding the angular work fine)

The log in pages look like this:

**Login.php**

```
    <form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='php/checklogin.php'>
    <form role='form'>
        <div class='form-group'>
             <label for='username'>Username</label><input type='text' class='form-control' id='myusername' name='myusername'>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
             <label for='password'>Password</label><input type='password' class='form-control' id='mypassword' name='mypassword'>
        </div>

  <button type='submit' id='Submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**checklogin.php**

```
    <?php

require("connect.php");


$myusername = $_POST['myusername'];             
$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];     



$query = $conn-> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='".$myusername."' AND password='".$mypassword."'");
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();

$result = $query->num_rows;

if ($result < 1 ){

    //header('Refresh: 2;url=..\login.php');
echo "<span style='color: red'>Wrong Username or Password. Try again.</span>";
       var_dump($myusername, $mypassword);

}


else if ($result > 0) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername']= $myusername;

    header('Refresh: 0;url=..\index.php');

}
else {
echo "oops, there was an error";
}
?>
```

For some reason I am now getting invalid username / password for any account I create when I try to log in with it.

The var dump shows the variable values are being set - ie (user="testuser" password="testpassword") and the user is in the database however the query is failing.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Also, if I add accounts in the database manually they are able to log in fine.

Is there something different with the way the angular form is submitting the values? I do not have much experience with it

Comment: if using default `$http` in angular to send data then `$_POST` will be empty since it will be sent as `application/json`. Need more detail on how data is submitted

Comment: I added the registration code to the post in register.php

Though I think I may have resolved the issue. My angular controller was set up as : 

`var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 


app.controller("validateCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.myusername = " ";
   $scope.myemail = " ";
   $scope.mypassword = " ";
  
});`
Removing the spaces in the scope variables seems to have fixed the issue. Not sure why that caused an issue as the database values did not have any extra whitespace